# Simplify if else conditions to reduce cognitive complexity in Java

Tags: java, sonarqube

Is there a way to simplify this java function?

Simplification is desired for maintainability of the code.

```
public void pushDocument(ESDocumentType esDocumentType, Object data, String documentId, long userId, long organizationId) {
    boolean proceed = false;

    if (esDocumentType.equals(ESDocumentType.XMLACTIVITY)) {
        proceed = Constants.ELASTIC_LOGGING_ENABLED && Constants.ELASTIC_XMLACTIVITY_ENABLED || Constants.SQS_LOGGING_ENABLED;
    }

    else if (esDocumentType.equals(ESDocumentType.XMLREQRES)) {
        proceed = Constants.ELASTIC_LOGGING_ENABLED && Constants.ELASTIC_XMLREQRES_ENABLED || Constants.SQS_LOGGING_ENABLED;
    }

    else if (esDocumentType.equals(ESDocumentType.ORDERHISTORY)) {
        proceed = Constants.ELASTIC_LOGGING_ENABLED && Constants.ELASTIC_ORDERHISTORY_ENABLED || Constants.SQS_LOGGING_ENABLED;
    }

    else if (esDocumentType.equals(ESDocumentType.SINGIN)) {
        proceed = Constants.ELASTIC_LOGGING_ENABLED && Constants.ELASTIC_SIGNIN_ENABLED || Constants.SQS_LOGGING_ENABLED;
    } else if (esDocumentType.equals(ESDocumentType.GOOGLESEARCH)) {
        proceed = Constants.ELASTIC_LOGGING_ENABLED && Constants.ELASTIC_GOOGLESEARCH_ENABLED || Constants.SQS_LOGGING_ENABLED;
    }

    if (proceed) {
        LogThread logThread = new LogThread();
        logThread.pushDocument(esDocumentType, data, documentId, userId, organizationId);
    }
}
```

Comment: All the expressions seem to start with `Constants.ELASTIC_LOGGING_ENABLED &&`, and end with `|| Constants.SQS_LOGGING_ENABLED`. Pull those out to surround the existing conditions.

Comment: Please check now

Comment: use a switch case instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possibility.  If I were doing this I would set up a map to grab the appropriate boolean.

```
public void pushDocument(ESDocumentType esDocumentType,
        Object data, String documentId, long userId,
        long organizationId) {
    
    
    boolean proceed = esDocumentType.equals(ESDocumentType.XMLACTIVITY);
    proceed = proceed || esDocumentType.equals(ESDocumentType.XMLREQRES);
    proceed = proceed || esDocumentType.equals(ESDocumentType.ORDERHISTORY);
    proceed = proceed || esDocumentType.equals(ESDocumentType.SINGIN);
    proceed = proceed ||  esDocumentType.equals(ESDocumentType.GOOGLESEARCH);
    
    
    // if any logging is to be done, proceed and one of the others must be true.
    if (proceed && (Constants.SQS_LOGGING_ENABLED
            || Constants.ELASTIC_LOGGING_ENABLE)) {
            LogThread logThread = new LogThread();
            logThread.pushDocument(esDocumentType, data,
                    documentId, userId, organizationId);
    }
}
```

Here is the alternative I mentioned.  The only difference is how `proceed` is determined.

```
Map<ESDocumentType, Boolean> docType = Map.of(
        ESDocumentType.EMLACTIVITY, Constants.ELASTIC_XMLACTIVITY_ENABLED,
        ESDocumentType.XMLREQRES, Constants.ELASTIC_XMLREQRES_ENABLED,
        ESDocumentType.ORDERHISTORY, Constants.ELASTIC_ORDERHISTORY_ENABLED,
        ESDocumentType.SINGIN, Constants.ELASTIC_SINGIN_ENABLED,
        ESDocumentType.GOOGLESEARCH, Constants.ELASTIC_GOOGLESEARCH_ENABLED);
    
public void pushDocument(ESDocumentType esDocumentType,
        Object data, String documentId, long userId,
        long organizationId) {
    
    
    boolean proceed = docType.getOrDefault(esDocumentType, false);
    
    // if any logging is to be done, proceed and one of the others must be true.
    if (proceed && (Constants.SQS_LOGGING_ENABLED
            || Constants.ELASTIC_LOGGING_ENABLE)) { 
                 LogThread logThread = new LogThread();
                 logThread.pushDocument(esDocumentType, data,
                      documentId, userId, organizationId);
    }
}
```

Comment: It will work Java9, I modified your code to support Java8

Answer (score 6):

I do not know your exact use case and you have to refine this a bit yourself but something like this will probably work.

```
List<ESDocumentType> enabled; // fill this based on your "Constant.ELASTIC_<BLAH>_ENABLED" constants in the constructor

public void pushDocument(ESDocumentType type, other parameters) {
    boolean proceed = (Constants.ELASTIC_LOGGING_ENABLED && enabled.contains(type)) || Constants.SQS_LOGGING_ENABLED;
    
    if (proceed) {
        LogThread logThread = new LogThread();
        logThread.pushDocument(esDocumentType, data, documentId, userId, organizationId);
    }
}
```

Comment: elegant, i give you that. +1

Comment: I think there is a flaw here.  If `Constants.SQS_LOGGING_ENABLED` is `true`, then logging will always occur regardless of the enabled test.  But that would not happen in the original construct since `proceed` could only be true if one of the document types was matched.

Comment: @WJS, fair enough - that could be solved with a second list. Like I said, I do not know the use case and that difference might not even be relevant.

Comment: What if you just assigned the output of `enabled.contains(type)` to proceed.  If true, it showed the condition was met.  You can then check for logging permission later.

Answer (score 3):

Use a switch statement, I think it should work like this (untested):

```
switch(ESDocumentType)
{
   case ESDocumentType.XMLACTIVITY:
        proceed = Constants.ELASTIC_LOGGING_ENABLED && 
        Constants.ELASTIC_XMLACTIVITY_ENABLED || Constants.SQS_LOGGING_ENABLED;
   break;
   
   [ .... add the other cases here]


   default:
     //we do not need to set proceed to false manually, but here would be the case for that
   break;

}
```

Comment: Also, it is really hard to follow the AND operators here. proceed is just a boolean, why not use magic numbers ( 1 or true ) for it?

Comment: It's the first time I see someone suggesting the use of magic numbers instead of dissuading someone from using them.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but sonarqube integration have some validations in method. That rules should failed the code if I use suggested one.

Comment: A better suggestion would be to take `proceed = Constants.ELASTIC_LOGGING_ENABLED` out of the `switch` and do something like `procede &= ...` inside the `switch`

Comment: A switch statement doesn't really reduce the complexity, though.

Comment: @Taschi *cognitive* complexity, that is "readable-ness", so to speak.

Comment: Good comments everybody. I was only thinking "well, it's a bool, so it really can only be 0 or 1". But on second thought, I think it is really 32 bit long here. Feel free to edit the answere if you find a better solution

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, even in that sense it is dubious how much easier the switch makes following the code.

Comment: @Taschi I find it reduces clutter, so, to me, it makes it more readable. I'm afraid we'll have to agree to disagree on this one :)

Comment: I would always preferre a switch statement over if-else branches, but that may be personal opinion based. In the background, a switch always inserts jump-tables instead of simple jump instructions, so from an assembler perspective it made the code more complex.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void pushDocument(ESDocumentType esDocumentType, Object data, String documentId, long userId, long organizationId) {

    boolean proceed = Constants.ELASTIC_LOGGING_ENABLED;

    if (esDocumentType.equals(ESDocumentType.XMLACTIVITY)) {
        proceed &&=  Constants.ELASTIC_XMLACTIVITY_ENABLED;
    }

    else if (esDocumentType.equals(ESDocumentType.XMLREQRES)) {
        proceed &&= Constants.ELASTIC_XMLREQRES_ENABLED;
    }

    else if (esDocumentType.equals(ESDocumentType.ORDERHISTORY)) {
        proceed &&= Constants.ELASTIC_ORDERHISTORY_ENABLED;
    }

    else if (esDocumentType.equals(ESDocumentType.SINGIN)) {
        proceed &&= Constants.ELASTIC_SIGNIN_ENABLED;
    }

    else if (esDocumentType.equals(ESDocumentType.GOOGLESEARCH)) {
        proceed &&= Constants.ELASTIC_GOOGLESEARCH_ENABLED;
    }

    if (proceed || Constants.SQS_LOGGING_ENABLED) {
        LogThread logThread = new LogThread();
        logThread.pushDocument(esDocumentType, data, documentId, userId, organizationId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Java8 use below code, It will help to avoid cognitive and cyclomatic complexity

```
public void pushDocument(ESDocumentType esDocumentType, Object data, String documentId, long userId, long organizationId) {
    EnumMap<ESDocumentType, Boolean> docType = new EnumMap<>(ESDocumentType.class);
    docType.put(ESDocumentType.XMLACTIVITY, Constants.ELASTIC_XMLACTIVITY_ENABLED);
    docType.put(ESDocumentType.XMLREQRES, Constants.ELASTIC_XMLREQRES_ENABLED);
    docType.put(ESDocumentType.ORDERHISTORY, Constants.ELASTIC_ORDERHISTORY_ENABLED);
    docType.put(ESDocumentType.SINGIN, Constants.ELASTIC_SIGNIN_ENABLED);
    docType.put(ESDocumentType.GOOGLESEARCH, Constants.ELASTIC_GOOGLESEARCH_ENABLED);
    boolean proceed = docType.getOrDefault(esDocumentType, false);
    if (proceed && Constants.ELASTIC_LOGGING_ENABLED || Constants.SQS_LOGGING_ENABLED) {
        LogThread logThread = new LogThread();
        logThread.pushDocument(esDocumentType, data, documentId, userId, organizationId);
    }
}
```